# Finding time-related patterns in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Ich have designed a graph in Neo4j that represents machines, events carried out on these machines and issues that occur on these machines. Every event and every issue is attached to a time-tree node. An example for one machine including its events and issues is shown in the picture below.

Now I try to find patterns that cause issues on machines. E.g. if the machine has 5 events per day; or 2 events per day and 5 days in a row; - then on x% of machines issues occure. Or if a machines aren't used for a long time they are more likely to get an issue...and so on.

So I am looking for a way to find **time-related patterns** using time-trees.

At the moment I am looking for patterns in 2 ways:

1. count number of events that happened before the issue, considering event types and related characteristics. - *but too trivial, time distances not included*
2. parallel visualization of multiple event streams (as on picture) of similar machines and manual search for anomalies. This one works even better with Graphileon InterActor,  *- but is not a nice solution since I work with hundreds of similar machines...*

Is there any way to find time-related patterns using CYPHER? The connectedness of time-trees should make it a nice use case for Neo4j right?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to **discover unknown patterns** in your graph, you are trying to make a **graph global operation**.

This type of operation is often made with a **graph compute engine** and not with a graph database, like Neo4j.

The authors (Ian Robinson, Jim Webber, & Emil Eifrem) of the book [Graph Databases](https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/) says that:

> A **graph compute engine** is a technology that enables global graph
>   computational algorithms to be run against large datasets. Graph
>   compute engines are designed to do things like identify clusters in
>   your data, or answer questions such as, “how many relationships, on
>   average, does everyone in a social network have?”

(Section "*Graph Compute Engines*", page 7)

Some tools suggested by the authors of the book:

- [Pegasus](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pegasus/)
- [Giraph](http://giraph.apache.org/)
- [Cassovary](https://github.com/twitter/cassovary)

Also, in the book [Learning Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/learning-neo4j-book/) (Section "*Why not use a graph database, and what to use instead*", page 40), Rik Van Bruggen says:

> While graph databases are extremely powerful at answering "graph local" questions, there is an
>   entire category of graph tools (often referred to as graph processing
>   engines or graph compute engines) that look at the graph global
>   problems.

That is: Neo4j is probably not a good tool to answer graph global operations like pattern discovery.

> The connectedness of time-trees should make it a nice use case for Noe4j right?

Yes, but to make CRUD operations, not graph global operations.